# Create an awaitable that awaits a method to be executed

Tags: c#, async-await

What I need to do is being able to await that a specific method is executed.

```
class MyClass
{
    public void TheMethodToAwait()
    {
        // Do something to signal that the method was invoked
    }

    public AnAwaitableObject TheMethodToAwaitWasExecuted()
    {
        // Need help in creating the awaitable object
    }
}
```

As you can see I want a method returning an awaitable object so that other classes may do the following:

```
await InstanceOfMyClass.TheMethodToAwaitWasExecuted();
```

I know the basics of creating custom awaitables but I'm struggling with this problem since I never did it in practice.

As usual any help is much appreciated, thanks

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

The method needs to be awaited multiple times. Actually it's the Update in a game Main Loop. My async methods do some work that must be synced with the loop. If the game runs at 60 FPS then the async methods need to do their job 60 times per second. Hope this makes more sense now.

**HOW I DID IT IN THE END**

For completeness sake I'll post my implementation too:

```
public class AwaitableEvent<TResult>
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<EventAwaiter<TResult>> _awaiterQueue;

    public AwaitableEvent()
    {
        _awaiterQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<EventAwaiter<TResult>>();
    }

    public EventAwaiter<TResult> GetAwaiter()
    {
        var awaiter = new EventAwaiter<TResult>();

        _awaiterQueue.Enqueue(awaiter);

        return awaiter;
    }

    public void Notify(TResult result)
    {
        var awaiterCount = _awaiterQueue.Count;

        while (awaiterCount-- > 0)
        {
            EventAwaiter<TResult> awaiter;

            if (_awaiterQueue.TryDequeue(out awaiter))
            {
                awaiter.Notify(result);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class EventAwaiter<TResult> : INotifyCompletion
{
    private Action _continuation;
    private TResult _result;

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public EventAwaiter()
    {
    }

    public void Notify(TResult result)
    {
        _result = result;

        _continuation();
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        _continuation = continuation;
    }

    public TResult GetResult()
    {
        return _result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider checking out [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Why do you not want to return a `Task`?  There is very rarely a reason to return anything else if you expect the caller to `await` that object.  Almost any time you see someone creating a custom awaitable object it's purely as an academic exercise to better understand what's going on behind the scenes, not for any practical purposes.

Comment: @Servy I have no problem returning a Task, it's just that I can't figure out how to achieve what I want. If you can do that using Task please add an answer with a code example.

Comment: @Dan Briant Would you mind adding an answer with a code example?

Comment: @dan Having no idea what you method is supposed to do, how could I *possibly* tell you how to do it?  You should return a `Task` here, almost certainly.  How you go about getting a `Task` to return is going to be *highly* dependent on what exactly this method does.  There are *lots* of ways of creating tasks, and they'll vary based on the underlying operation performed, and what other tools you're using to create the inherent asynchrony.

Comment: @Servy Nope! I just need a bunch of async methods to stop untill the MyClass.MethodToAwait() method is invoked. What the method does  is of no importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I understand better what you're doing, I can recommend an approach I took for a simulation system.  I wanted a way to write scripts that could 'await' the next simulation update cycle, which is very much like a frame in a game loop.  I originally used TaskCompletionSource, but the overload was problematic due to constructing this on every await.  I eventually created a custom awaiter like this:

Simple base class to implement an 'always-incomplete' awaitable (basically just a collection of continuations to fire):

```
public abstract class Awaiter : INotifyCompletion
{
    private readonly List<Action> _continuations = new List<Action>();

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public abstract void GetResult();

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        lock (_continuations)
        {
            var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            if (syncContext != null)
            {
                _continuations.Add(() => syncContext.Send(s => continuation(), null));
            }
            else
            {
                _continuations.Add(continuation);
            }                
        }
    }

    public void RunContinuations()
    {
        Action[] continuations;
        lock (_continuations)
        {
            continuations = _continuations.ToArray();
            _continuations.Clear();
        }
        foreach (var continuation in continuations)
        {
            continuation();
        }
    }

    public Awaiter GetAwaiter()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Inside the Simulation class was this (you would `await CycleExecutedEvent()` to use it):

```
private readonly CycleExecutedAwaiter _awaiter = new CycleExecutedAwaiter();

        public Awaiter CycleExecutedEvent()
        {
            if (!IsRunning) throw new TaskCanceledException("Simulation has been stopped");
            return _awaiter;
        }

        private sealed class CycleExecutedAwaiter : Awaiter
        {
            public override void GetResult()
            {
                var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current as ScriptingSynchronizationContext;
                if (syncContext != null && syncContext.StopRequested)
                    throw new TaskCanceledException("Stop Requested");
            }
        }
```

Hopefully this is similar enough to your use case to be helpful.

---

Important note:

This implementation includes some synchronization context trickery that you might want to strip out.  I needed to control the thread used for scripting purposes and also wanted to block my update loop while giving scripts time to execute.  Your requirements may vary; for instance, you may want to run continuations asynchronously using Task.Run.  This should at least give a skeleton for how to get started, though.

Comment: I'm still digesting the code but it seems what I was looking for. Actually I'm implementing something similiar to a scripting system... I'm trying to understand the SynchronizationContext thing but I think I can study it by myself on MSDN.

Comment: @dan, The synchronization context had to do with allowing forced interruption of scripts; it was a bit of a hack and probably isn't too applicable to what you're doing.  If you just want to execute in the context of your game loop thread, you can omit it entirely.

Comment: Yes I got the purpose. Well, my system would be more robust with a way to stop the execution of a Script by force so I'll try to better understand your code.

Comment: I used a simplified implementation but the idea is the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a single signal (not something that can be "set" and then later "unset" and "set" again), then you can use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`:

```
class MyClass
{
  private readonly TaskCompletionSource<object> _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  public void TheMethodToAwait()
  {
    _tcs.TrySetResult(null);
  }

  public Task TheMethodToAwaitWasExecutedAsync()
  {
    return _tcs.Task;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah seems a step in the right direction. Anyway I need to reuse this. Actually MethodToAwait() is the Update in a game Main Loop. My async methods need to await the beginning of a new frame to do their processing so that if the game runs at 60 FPS they do their job 60 times per second. So I need to reuse the completion source somehow. Is that achievable?

Comment: Sadly I see that TaskCompletionSource<T> is not reusable. So I should go back to the custom awaitable object idea. Maybe I could create my own ReusableTaskCompletionSource<T>.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need something that can be "unset" and "reset", what you're really looking for is the [asynchronous equivalent of a manual-reset event](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266920.aspx). You could build your own or [use one from my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncManualResetEvent):

```
class MyClass
{
  private readonly AsyncManualResetEvent _mre = new AsyncManualResetEvent();

  public void TheMethodToAwait()
  {
    _mre.Set();
  }

  public Task TheMethodToAwaitWasExecutedAsync()
  {
    return _mre.WaitAsync();
  }

  // TODO: some code that calls _mre.Reset()
}
```

Comment: This is interesting and seems easy to understand/use. I'll take a look at the source code later, thank you.

Comment: Your implementation is very elegant but I can't use it because I'd need to reset the event at every frame of the game. At 60 FPS it would mean 60 resets per second. That would cause allocation on the heap of a new TaskCompletionSource (the one used internally) 60 times per second. That won't be very garbage-collector friendly. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use `await` at all within a game loop.

Comment: It's not inside the game loop. I'm experimenting with the possibility of creating various async scripts to implement game logic. A feature I need is that these scripts can, if they want to, sync with the game main loop by awaiting the beginning of the next frame. To do so the main loop must send a signal to all the awaiters. Using your class I would need to reset the event every frame and that would introduce too many allocations. And, honestly, I'm not even sure it could be done using it.